# Generate vertices for a polygon

Tags: java, opengl-es, polygon, vector-graphics

I'm trying to make a useful/generic 2D polygon class for an OpenGL ES renderer.
When I create a polygon, I give it several parameters:

```
Polygon(Vector3 centerpoint, int numVertices, float inPolySize)
```

Then, I try to generate the vertices. This is where i'm having a tough time. I need to determine the number of vertices, get an angle, find the x/y position of that angle, someone take the size into account, AND offset by the position.

OpenGL works with big arrays of data. Nothing is nice like Lists of Vector3's. Instead it's float[] arrays, with the first index being X1, second being Y1, third being Z1, fourth being X2, etc...

```
final int XPOS = 0;
final int YPOS = 1;
final int ZPOS = 2;
int mvSize = 3; // (x, y, z);
float[] vertices = new float[mvSize * mNumVertices];
for (int verticeIndex = 0; verticeIndex < mNumVertices; verticeIndex++)
{
    double angle = 2 * verticeIndex * Math.PI / mNumVertices;
    vertices[mvSize * verticeIndex + XPOS] = (((float)Math.cos(angle)) * mPolygonSize) + mPosition.GetX();
    vertices[mvSize * verticeIndex + YPOS] = (((float)Math.sin(angle)) * mPolygonSize) + mPosition.GetY();
    vertices[mvSize * verticeIndex + ZPOS] = mPolygonSize + mPosition.GetZ();
}
```

Unfortunatley, my triangle is never quite right. It's skewed a lot, the size doesn't seem right...

I figure i'm throwing the size into the wrong formula, can anyone help?

EDIT:
Here's some sample data
Polygon test = new Polygon( new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 3, .5f);

> vertices[0] = -0.25
>
> vertices[1] = 1.4330127
>
> vertices[2] = 0.0
>
> vertices[3] = -0.25
>
> vertices[4] = 0.5669873
>
> vertices[5] = 0.0
>
> vertices[6] = 0.5
>
> vertices[7] = 1.0
>
> vertices[8] = 0.0
>
> vertices[9] = -0.25
>
> vertices[10] = 1.4330127
>
> vertices[11] = 0.0

Comment: Can you run your algorithm, print out the resulting array, and post it  here?

Comment: The code is working fine; somehow the output seems not to match the calculation. E.g., `vertices[0]=Math.cos(0)*0.5f+0.0f=1.0f*0.5f=0.5f`. (granted the code just stores the ctor parameters in the fields...)

Comment: @StefanHanke I ommited a bunch of code, including the fact that the first set of points is actually the centerpoint, for purposes of drawing a filled circle. That WAS a bug though, which I fixed, so thank you! I think i'll greatly simplify my code to match the questions first, before continuing to figure out what the bug is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I was this stupid. Basically, my render window was smaller than my screen. If my screen is a rectangle, my render window was a square.

This being the case, any triangle I draw that was up was clipped by my render window. To me, it looked like the triangle was skewed. Really, it was just clipped!

Answer (score 0):

The Java math library takes radians as input, not degrees. I didn't see the angles you were using for your calculation, but if you're not converting to radians from degrees, you will get some skewed looking shapes, and would explain that your calculations are correct, but the expected result is off.

Comment: I left this dead for awhile, I appologize. What's crazy is that this java OpenGL ES library takes code in.. degrees. Check it: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glRotatef/ It sort of baffles me why OpenGL, of all things, would accept rotation in anything but radians.

Comment: Hahaha oh wow that's weird. Especially considering most of the other libraries I can think of off the top of my head use radians.

Comment: Um although now that I think of it, even if the GL library you're using takes degrees, the java Math library takes radians (I can see you're calling Math.sin and Math.cos). So if you're going back and forth you'll need to covert from degrees to radians.